# Is it possibile to show a label next to the corresponding field with the workitem web layout of DevOps 2019?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I'm upgrading my custom process template from TFS 2017 on premises to DevOps Server 2019 on premises.
In TFS 2017 was possible to show label next to corresponding field, like those highlighted in the following image:

[image]

Is possible to do the same in DevOps 2019. I'm succeed only to show label above corresponding field:

[image]

I'd like to show label next to corresponding field (see following image obtained with paint) because it reduces the amount of vertical space used and so more information can be shown without the user having to use the vertical scroll bar:

[image]

If is possible, could you please answer me with a example of snippet of xml code that realize it [using web layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported. There is a user voice that you could vote and track it.
[Support to custom layout, such as show a label next to the corresponding field with the workitem web layout](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1075830/support-to-custom-layout-such-as-show-a-label-next.html)